# Настроить spf. Что прописать?

Tags: dns, email, gmail, spf

Я не знаю, что важно, поэтому опишу всю цепочку

- Хостинг nic.ru
- Домен reg.ru.
- Там прописаны ns-сервера cloudflare
- Соответственно, DNS управляется на cloudflare
- В cloudflare прописаны MX записи для Яндекс Почты для Домена (ПДД)
- В ПДД создан ящик info@domain.com

Все работает прекрасно, почта ходит отлично. Осталась последняя проблема, если отсылать почту прямо с сервера (`PHPMailer`), то gmail пишет получена `no-reply@domain.com через xxx.nichost.ru`. Для этого существует `SPF`, но я совсем запутался (многое попробовал) и перестаю понимать какую именно запись SPF надо прописать, для того чтобы почта уходила напрямую, без этого вот `через`.

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1311182?hl=ru&authuser=0 Ну тут написано несколько по-другому.

Comment: Понял, это гугловская особенность восприятия SPF, не знал. В общем смотрите как пишутся SPF записи и указываете в ней обязательно тот ip с которого отправляется ваша почта и который как раз резолвится как xxx.nichost.ru

Comment: т.е. что то типа `v=spf1 +a +mx ip4:1.2.3.4 -all` пишется она как TXT запись самого домена

Comment: Для проверки что все правильно, запускаете nslookup в нем даете команду `set q=TXT` после чего вводите имя своего домена. Вы должны увидеть вашу spf запись.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае виноват nic.ru. Почта должна быть либо заведена у них (строго), либо у вас должен быть какой-то более дорогой тариф, который позволяет использовать другие SMTP-сервера.

Еще раз — при связке nic.ru + яндекс ППД никак нельзя избавиться от "отправлено через".

Answer (score 1):

Надо так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ip4:x.x.x.x ~all

v=spf1 redirect=_spf.yandex.net

Это работающие записи на cloudflare.

Comment: Это неправильно работающие записи. Некоторые буржуйские почтовые сервисы не примут ваше письмо. spf запись должна быть одна и содержать в себе весь набор правил. Редирект нужно так же разворачивать в конкретику.

Comment: Такой буржуйский сервер, как google, прекрасно это принимает. Яндекс тоже принимает. Приведите пример, "некоторых" буржуйских серверов, которые не принимают. А поводу разворачивания редиректа - адресуйте свое замечание в Яндекс. Он именно так рекомендует указывать spf.

Comment: Яндекс считает, что почта будет ходить только через их сервера, и в таком контексте запись верна, В вашем случае верной будет такая запись `"include:_spf-ipv4.yandex.ru include:_spf-ipv6.yandex.ru include:_spf.google.com ip4:x.x.x.x ~all"`. Гуглом и яндексом интернет не ограничивается. P.S. Рекомендация от гугла тут: https://support.google.com/a/answer/4568483?hl=en